# How to detect wireless signals around me?

Tags: android, signals, wireless

Is there a way to detect any kind of wireless signal using Android phone and identify it? Or must the signal be some sort of pre-defined one like Wi-fi? or used by spy devices like hidden camera.i want android devices act as spy finder devices

Thanks.

Comment: u want to connect hidden wireless camera on android?

Comment: no yar.i want to detect hidden camera signals

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on what sensors, hardware & drivers your phone has. Android can only use the hardware existing on your phone.